# Facebook PageView event ignore if anchor changes but url remains

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, magento2, facebook-pixel

so I'm currently loading to my page head the facebook pixel code and automatically sending a PageView event after its loaded but for some reason its tracking anchor changes when I would like to avoid this.

My website has a cart for example and when I open it as a side panel it adds a #cart to the url but the user didn't really change url and tracking anchor changes is just creating miss information in our statistics and I was wondering if there was a way to ignore anchor changes?

```
<!-- Meta Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
    <?php
    $dataProcessingOptionsCode = $block->getDataProcessingOptionsJSCode();
    if (strlen($dataProcessingOptionsCode) > 0) {
        echo $dataProcessingOptionsCode."\n";
    }
    ?>
fbq(
  'init',
  '<?= $block->getFacebookPixelID() ?>',
    <?= $block->getPixelInitCode() ?>,
  {agent: '<?= $block->getFacebookAgentVersion() ?>' }
);
fbq('track', 'PageView', {
  source: "<?= $block->getSource() ?>",
  pluginVersion: "<?= $block->getPluginVersion() ?>"
});
</script>
```